# How to match Container's Width with Other Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi, I am new to Flutter. I'm trying to develop a screen, where there are two containers. As you can see in the image above, the first container has a horizontally symmetric width, but the second container with "Date and Time" is smaller than the above container as it should be equal. This is what I've done:

```
  class _CurrentTabState extends State<CurrentTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "YOUR BOOKINGS",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey
              )
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                  "Fri. 12 Jul - 18:00"
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, for any reason can't you set an specific width for those containers?

Comment: I can but, then how will I handle the AutoLayout/Responsiveness part? In Swift, I can use AutoLayout to manage a `UIView's` width with leading and trailing anchors, how can I do the same in flutter? If I gave a width of 500, may be it will cut off in `iPhone 5s` and it will not be responsive any more.

Comment: @Rob maybe try `Expanded` widget

Comment: Already tried, I know that I can get the screenWidth using MediaQuery and then setting  `width = screenWidth * 0.9` of `Container` Widget will give me the exact width, but is it the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give those Containers a width, and still keep them responsive. I'll show you two options:

1. If you want them to use the whole screen width, you can use the `infinity` constant:

   ```
   Container(
     width: double.infinity,
   ),
   ```

Then you can give it some space on the sides with padding.

2. Use MediaQuery:

   ```
   Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 0.5, // Or whatever proportion you need.
   ),
   ```

If you use this second option, you might want to keep them centered. You can achieve that with the `mainAxisAlignment` from your `Column`:

```
return Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  ...
);
```

Comment: So, I am using the 2nd method now and it's already working for me. Which one do you think is the best solution first one or the second one?

Comment: Generally, if I need the Container to use the whole screen width, I use double.infinity and some Padding. If it's another size, then I'll go for MediaQuery. I've updated my answer with a comment on how to center them too. :)

Comment: Thanks, one more question, what does `double.infinity` do?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not really sure how it works under the hood on Dart. But if you pass double.infinity to a widget's width or height it tells it to use all the available space. If you, for example, rotate the screen, it will resize automatically to the new dimensions. Infinity is not a number actually. So I believe that when a `Container` receives a double.infinity value, what it does behind is to set the constraints to the size of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the attribute `width: double.infinity,` in both Containers.